# Trying to create a filtered view for a simple employee in out list

Tags: 2013

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and am trying to create a Sign In/Out list so when my employees leave the office they can "sign out" with a `date/time` column for when they will leave and another for when they are returning.  Other employees in the office use this list to see when their counterparts are returning.  I'm having trouble creating an accurate filtered view for these remaining employees as `[Today]` isn't helpful with time.  I would like the filtered view to only show items (people out) when `Departing date/time <= Now() >= Returning date/time` but am not having any luck.  This way people can sign out in advance if they need and would never have to sign in as the filtered view (in comparison to the refresh time of now) would essentially take care of all of this.

Thank you and I look forward to seeing how far I overthought this whole thing...

Comment: Wow, nothing?  This must be harder than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I figured it out. Open the view of your list in SharePoint Designer and use the find feature for DateTime. Your date/time columns will have a value of  Simply add IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" and [Today] in your filtered view will now be able to filter down to the minute not just the day. Your final value in SharePoint Designer will look like this

I hope this helps you!